# Hexadecimal entities are changed in UTF characters

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

In my XML some hexa decimal entities are there when i am transforming its changed into UTF - 8.

**INPUT FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>a text.</a>
    <b>b &#x2013; text.</b>
</root>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
<root>
    <a>a text.</a>
    <b>b – text.</b>
</root>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>a text.</a>
    <b>b &#x2013; text.</b>
</root>
```

Comment: So why are Unicode characters a problem if you use encoding as UTF-8? The XSLT processor uses an XML parser to parse your input into a tree with text nodes containing Unicode characters, it does not know whether the original input document contained a character reference or a character literally so it can't preserve character references. What you can do in XSLT 2 or later is define a character map to map certain characters to a different output string representation, so that way you could define that any dash in the result tree is serialized as a character reference.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to know WHY you need this, because different techniques might or might not meet your requirement.

One approach is to specify US-ASCII as the output encoding. Then all non-ASCII characters will appear as numeric entities (character references) in the output. Unfortunately this also means you can't use non-ASCII characters in element or attribute names.

Comment: Thank you, @Micheal its work for me now. As per client requirement i am receiving XML and process it into HTML, In-design and XML too but after conversion of XML all entities changed as above and client asked for after process the out XML should exactly matched with my INPUT xml so that i need that. still the code  `<firstname>Fran&#x00E7;ois</firstname>` and output is  `<firstname>Fran&#xe7;ois</firstname>` lets see if they are ok! Thanks again

Comment: Exact matching with your input is not possible in XSLT: there is no way of distinguishing a percent sign written as `%` from one written as `&#x25;`. It's also an absurd requirement: sometimes you have to tell the client that you understand the technology better than they do.

Answer (score 1):

Add Character map to your script as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" use-character-maps="entity"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="entity">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x2013;" string="&amp;#x2013;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <a>a text.</a>
        <b>b &#x2013; text.</b>
    </root>
```

See process http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qM2e2b

Comment: Thank you @Rupesh for the reply. Actually i am searching for another alternate because the list of entities are not handy and our script will run online application if some another entities will appear in the XML then our program will stuck, If any other alternate is with you please update. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Amrendra, I think for this type of scenario, you need to try to write a pre-processor for your input that convert all input &..; to &amp;..;. that will solve your problem